# PHP MySQL: Writing file details to DB while using Uploadify

Tags: php, mysql, uploadify

I'm uploading files (images) to my file structure using Uploadify, then catching each file, giving it a random number as a file name, resizing it using the excellent SimpleImage script into Large, Medium, and Small sizes, saving those to the directory, discarding the original image, and writing the file details (the random number, the original name, the album ID, etc) to the database for access later.

All of this is working without a hitch escept the writing to the DB part. I find only the first file's information is passed to the DB, and with an incorrect number as the filename.

In short, how can I write EACH file's information to the Database (correctly), when using Uploadify on multiple images?

My current script:

*note: AlbumID is set dynamically by the user and posted as filedata to uploadify.

```
require_once '../../functions.php';
require_once '../../conn.php';

//defaults
$uploadify_path = '/contents/uploads/gallery/';
$albumID = $_POST['AlbumID'];

//Define a destination
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_POST['path']; // Relative to the root

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetFile = $targetPath . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/SimpleImage.php');

// Validate the file type
$fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
$fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
    $ran = $albumID.RandNumber(10);
    $location=$targetPath.$ran;

    $LegacyName = $fileParts['filename'];
    $FileExt = $fileParts['extension'];

    if(is_numeric($albumID)) {
        $q = "INSERT INTO gallery_meta (AlbumID, FileName, LegacyName, FileExt, IsDefault, Public)
                VALUES ('$albumID','$ran','$LegacyName','$FileExt','0','1')";
        $r= mysql_query($q);
        mysql_free_result($r);
    }

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($targetFile);

    $image = new SimpleImage();
    $image->load($targetFile);

    if( $height >= 901 ) {
        $image->resizeToHeight(900);
        $image->save($location.'-lrg.'.$FileExt);
        $image->resizeToHeight(550);
        $image->save($location.'-med.'.$FileExt);
        $image->resizeToHeight(200);
        $image->save($location.'-sm.'.$FileExt);
        unlink($targetFile);
    }
    elseif(( $height  >= 551 )&&( $height <= 900 )) {
        $image->save($location.'-lrg.'.$FileExt);
        $image->resizeToHeight(550);
        $image->save($location.'-med.'.$FileExt);
        $image->resizeToHeight(200);
        $image->save($location.'-sm.'.$FileExt);
        unlink($targetFile);
    }
    elseif(( $height >= 201 )&&( $height <= 550 )) {
        $image->save($location.'-lrg.'.$FileExt);
        $image->save($location.'-med.'.$FileExt);
        $image->resizeToHeight(200);
        $image->save($location.'-sm.'.$FileExt);
        unlink($targetFile);
    }
    if( $height  <= 200 ) {
        $image->save($location.'-lrg.'.$FileExt);
        $image->save($location.'-med.'.$FileExt);
        $image->save($location.'-sm.'.$FileExt);
        unlink($targetFile);
    }

    echo '1';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid file type.';
}
}
```

Comment: what's your db table structure?

Comment: AlbumID  int(11)
FileName  int(30)
LegacyName  varchar(250)
FileExt  varchar(11)
IsDefault  tinyint(1)
Caption  longtext (NULL)
Created  timestamp (NULL)
Public   tinyint(1)

Comment: @Dreadedsemicolon Incidentally, the number being stored in the DB (instead of the random 10-digit number (plus albumID) assigned as the new filename) is 2147483647 - the max for a 32 bit signed integer. That same variable, however, is being stored on the file no problem: e.g 14294985474-lrg.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add an auto incrementing key to the table, and change albumID into a `BIGINT` if you're sure your values aren't going to overflow the size of `BIGINT`, but if they are I recommend you save the "AlbumId" as a `VARCHAR(30)` instead, since it's more of a name than an actual number key, especially since it looks like it can be an arbitrary length.

I also think that instead of a random number at the end, you should be appending the current timestamp using `time()` so that you don't create the potential of collisions like a system with random numbers & user input will.

Also incidentally, `$_POST['albumId']`, by being direct user input.. is leaving your database open to a [MySQL Injection](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGkQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection&ei=wtoCUNmyIom4rQGj6JCyDA&usg=AFQjCNGcGZNbIk2jM8itxItHrCja7eJ0PQ) attack.

Comment: I was just answering to this effect myself :)

I changed the `RandNumber()` function to give me an 8 digit number instead of 10, and then cast `$ran` as an integer. Seems to have solved the problem.

I looked into BIGINT, but that zerofills (I believe), and that doesn't suit my purposes here.

`$_POST['albumID']` is only written to the db on being an integer. I feel that should be sufficient. I could be wrong?

Comment: I think BIGINT only zerofills if you tell it to.  I still think it's problematic to use a random number appended to the file unless you're going to do a db search to make sure there is no collision. ;)

Comment: I tried, because your argument is sound, changing to `time()` and retructured the FileName field to BIGINT (unsigned). Bizarrely, it throws the same problem as before - only the first file is parsed, and the filename is stored as 2147483647 again. The problem at this point MUST be in my table structure, but I really can't see where...

Comment: ...actually - scratch that - I see it is only saving the first file now too (before, all files were saved regardless).

Comment: Ended up with the following working solution. The problem was using `intval` - it was maxing out after I prepended the `$albumID`. So - `$ran = microtime();` `$parts = explode(".",$ran);` `$ran = preg_replace( '/\s+/', '', $parts[1] );` `$ran = $albumID.$ran;`